# pdf is not generated using jspdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jspdf

Code:

```
var doc = jsPDF();
var getImageFromUrl = function(url, callback) {
  var img = new Image();

  img.onError = function() {
    alert('Cannot load image: "'+url+'"');
  };
  img.onload = function() {
    callback(img);
  };
  img.src = url;
}
var createPDF = function(imgData) {




  doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 50, 50, 'monkey'); 
  doc.addPage(); 

}
var image = "some image url"
 getImageFromUrl(image, createPDF);
doc.text(35, 25, "Some extra text")
 doc.output('datauri');
```

No images are shown in pdf output? How to solve this issue? As the image is generating inside a function, will this be the reason for not generating the image? I want last 2 lines of code outside the function `createPDF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have too put last two line inside the callback function in order to work. If you don't want this than you could use some flag.

```
var flag=0
    var createPDF = function(imgData) {




  doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 50, 50, 'monkey'); 
  doc.addPage(); 


 if(flag==0)
    doc.output('datauri');



}


   var image = "some image url"
  flag =1 ;
     getImageFromUrl(image, createPDF);
    doc.text(35, 25, "Some extra text")



     flag=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import jspdf from 'jspdf'; // import it at the top

**write below in your function where you want to download it** 


let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'pt', 'a3');
pdf.html(document.getElementById('pdfTable'), {
    callback: function () {
        pdf.save('resume.pdf');   
    }
});
```